# Is there a name for this fibonacci-like sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, oeis

A programming problem I'm playing with gives the following sequence:

$R(0) = 1$

$R(1) = 1$

$R(2) = 2$

$R(2n) = R(n) + R(n + 1) + n (for\; n > 1)$

$R(2n + 1) = R(n - 1) + R(n) + 1 (for\; n >= 1)$

Is this a known sequence or is this just something the creator thought up of? If it is real, is it in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/)?

Comment: The first few terms of your sequence are $1,1,2,3,7,4,13... $ which can be searched in OEIS for an appropriate result.

Comment: Should one of the inequalities be switched?

Comment: @mikevandernaald No.

Comment: Woops, sorry about that.  You are right.